# Synology Docker - Automatically start server with nodemon

Tags: docker, synology

I'm a beginner with docker. In Synology, I'm able to create a container through an image via their UI and customize it without touching any configuration file. When I configure my container to run the "nodemon" `CMD` I use `nodemon --watch /server/snapshots/server.js /server/snapshots/server.js`. The problem is that the container stops and the log displays this: `Error: Cannot find module '/nodemon'`. I don't know how to install nodemon without a terminal. In Synology UI, inside each container, there is a terminal area, but it's only accessible once the container is running... which I cannot access because the error stops the container. I tried to edit the `CMD` via their UI, but it's read-only, so I'm not sure what I can do next. **How can I install nodemon in a Synology container and use it to start my server when my container starts?**

Previously I was able run nodemon but only because the container did not start any node.js server automatically. I would have to, via Synology UI, open the terminal and run `cd /server/snapshots/ && nodemon server.js` myself and it would work until the container restarted. But now I'm trying to have container automatically start my server using nodemon.